# Cannot put .svc file to IIS hosted WebDAV directory - logs say HTTP error 405

Tags: wcf, webdav, put

I am trying to publish via something more reliable than the FTP option, which works very intermittently from visual studio - and is very slow. So let me first ask you: In 2011, using visual studio to publish, is WebDAV the best option?

Anyway, I've got WebDAV hosted by IIS 7 up and running, and I have managed to map it as a drive. I can copy files there aswell, except anything with the file extension .svc. I can publish everything else I've tried, and also publish the .svc file if I first rename it to something else, then renaming back after it already is in the WebDAV directory.

Here is the IIS log:

```
2011-03-19 18:32:54 192.168.0.9 PROPFIND /bin/service.svc - 80 SERVER\User my.ip.not.shown Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600 405 0 0 0
```

As you can see, it ends in 405.

The only similar thing I've managed to google up could be solved by configuring the ,  and  sections of the applicationHost file. The logical thing would be to check for an entry in , but it says nothing about .svc. I've also tried setting applyToWebDAV to false.

Any ideas?

*UPDATE:*

Thinking on it, could it simply be that the WCF http handler intercepts the url, since .svc is registered with that handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. The WCF handler was ordered before the WebDAV handler in the handler mappings, so it intercepted requests to *.svc. It in turn returned 405 method not allowed for PROPFIND.

Simply move the WebDAV entry upwards in the list until it is listed appropriately early in the mappings.